# Normal reaction force in air

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces

Generally normal reaction is defined between two objects or surface, but when we talk about an object moving in air who do we consider as applying the normal reaction

Answer (score 1):

There is a *normal* force when an object goes into the air, which is also called the *buoyant* force (due to air). The naming is just a convention, but it is called the buoyant force as the object in particular influencing the motion of this particular object is a *fluid*. Now, the object is now under influence from two forces due to the air above and below it). But one of them is smaller than the other and so there will be a net force (from Newton's laws).

Comment: The buoyant force IS the SUM of normal  forces acting on the surface of an object in a fluid.

Comment: I have edited the part that the normal force here is the buoyant force.

Answer (score 1):

The term "normal force" merely refers to the component of (mainly) atomic/molecular-based electromagnetic interaction with other matter.  When we have large composite objects such as blocks and tables interacting with each other, we lump all those interactions into two classes of forces by breaking them down into components parallel and perpendicular to each other: the parallel components of interaction we call "friction" and the perpendicular components we call "normal."  Normal simply means the perpendicular component of the interaction force.

When two objects collide, we can talk about the tangential and normal components of the interaction/force which they exert on each other.  Just because its not a block on a table doesn't mean their is no "normal" force. Of course, there is! Normal means perpendicular, and the force is merely an interaction, usually electromagnetic.

This idea that somehow the "normal force" is a force separate unto itself and is a "reaction" force is false. **No force is a reaction force!**  Interactions which result in a force on an object always result in a force on the second object. Neither happens as a reaction to the other. They both happen simultaneously.  Call the "other" force (the one that isn't in your free-body diagram) a 3rd Law pair force.

In air, a solid object is constantly colliding with molecules which exert forces on the object (and the object exerts 3rd law pair forces on the molecules). These forces can be broken down into components which are parallel/tangential to the surface where the collision occured and perpendicular to the surface. The net resultant force from a set of collisions  net forces which can be characterized as "normal" to each surface. In a fluid, the vector sum of all the surface normals results in a non-zero force which we call the buoyant force if there is a gravitational field.

Answer (score -1):

In physics, the normal force is the reactional force that justifies why an object with mass under the influence of gravity remain motionless. If you want to force a definition of normal out of a mass moving in air, we can be able to say the air resistance on a falling body at the point where it reaches terminal velocity is a normal force. But truly, normal force is for stuffs sitting on a table or somewhat.